# I need some help about ban command in discord bot

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I want to add a ban command that only works if the user who sent it has the Administrator, Owner and Moderator permission. Is there a way I could do this?

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.guild) return;

  if (message.content.startsWith('+ban')) {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (user) {
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      if (member) {
        member.ban({
          reason: 'They were bad!',
        }).then(() => {
          message.channel.sendMessage(`${user} BAN!`);
        }).catch(err => {
          message.channel.sendMessage('Bu çar çok güçlü, banlayamıyorum.');
          console.error(err);
        });
      } else {
        message.channel.sendMessage('Kullanıcı sunucuda değil.');
      }
    } else {
      message.channel.sendMessage('Adını ver banlayayım, sahip.');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: In the future, please only add tags relevant to the problem. The `atom-editor` tag was removed since it's unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways of doing this!

You could do this by checking the message author's permissions that he has on this Discord server. I would use the [`hasPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission) method to check which permissions the user actually has. All permission flags can be found **[here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS)**.

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return ('You aren\'t an Administrator');
```

---

You could even do it by checking the message author's userID. Just compare the userID of the message author and your predefined userID:

```
if (message.author.id !== 'ID OF THE USER') return ('You aren\'t an Administrator');
```

Comment: i solved this from this way. is there any problem? can u check?
http://dpaste.com/104KKMM

Comment: yea it worked well but i have one more trouble can u text me your discord id if u wanna help

Comment: I don't like this that much. I would be happy if you still continue to ask your questions here :)

Comment: oh okay then how can i make a punish command. like i write 
```+punish @user x hours``` and he will only see the chat for punisheds and channels for

Comment: Please create a new question for this @ErayÖzden